# How to use ocpu.r_fun_call?

Tags: r, opencpu

I am able to use the opencpu function `ocpu.rpc`. But not the function `ocpu_r_fun_call`. Why the above code does not work?

```
<html>
  <head>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.opencpu.org/opencpu-0.4.js"></script>

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#submitbutton").click(function(){
          var req = ocpu.r_fun_call("mean", {"x" : 10}, function(session){
            $("#namefield").val(session);
          });
        });

    });

    </script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <input type="text" id="namefield" value="">

    <button id="submitbutton" type="button">Submit!</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

I also tried:

```
$("#submitbutton").click(function(){
  var req = ocpu.r_fun_call("mean", {"x" : 10}, function(session){
    session.getObject(function(data){
      $("#namefield").val(data);
    });
  });
});
```

And I also tried with `session.getConsole`, and also:

```
  var req = ocpu.r_fun_call("mean", {"x" : 10}, function(session){
$("#submitbutton").on("click", function(){
    $("#namefield").val(session.getObject());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problems were:

- the js function is `ocpu.call`, not `ocpu.r_fun_call`
- the fact that the `mean` function does not belong to my package. If I put an `average` function in my package:

  average <- mean

Then I can use it with `opencpu` like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="opencpu/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="opencpu/opencpu-0.4.js"></script>

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#submitbutton").on("click", function(){

        var req = ocpu.call("average", {
          x : 10
        }, function(session){
          session.getObject(function(data){
                $("#namefield").val(data)
              });
        });

        //if R returns an error, alert the error message
        req.fail(function(){
          alert("Server error: " + req.responseText);
        });

      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <button id="submitbutton" type="button">Submit!</button>
    <input type="text" id="namefield" value="">

  </body>
</html>
```

Note the tip to know more when there's a problem:

```
    //if R returns an error, alert the error message
    req.fail(function(){
      alert("Server error: " + req.responseText);
    });
```